# AWS Get Short Term temp token from SSO AD Connector

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-sts, aws-sso

I have an on premp AD linked to AWS SSO using AD Connector. 
AD Users have MFA enabled in AWS SSO.

There is a requirement of an application to retrieve short term token using user ID. Example Active Directory User ID 'A' has access to shutdown a EC2 instance. User ID 'A' logins in to the custom application, custom application retrieves the short term token and uses this token to shutdown the EC2 instance.

This application is build specifically for business users who are not comfortable using AWS Console, hence a very basic minimal easy to use UI.

I have read through a lot of AWS documentation and all the implementation I have checked online is for AWS SSO with SAML Federated with Azure AD etc but not with on premp AD.

How can STS be used with on premp AD SSO implementation?

Comment: I did a bit of more searching and it seems AWS SSO implementation with AD Connector doesnt have STS implemented. I not fully sure yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is confirmed. SSO with AD connector doesnt have STS implemented.